# ¿que permisos se le da a un usuario para que pueda crear usuarios en mysql workbench y no me de error?

Tags: base-de-datos, mysql-workbench

Al intentar crear un nuevo usuario con mi usuario existente me da el siguiente error:

```
Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the CREATE USER privilege(s) for this operation
```

¿Qué permisos tendría que asignar al primer usuario para que este pueda crear nuevos usuarios?

Comment: [¿Mismo caso?](/q/124675/)

Comment: @padaleiana puede ser, pero como no tiene ni respuesta ni siquiera vale la pena referenciarla...

Comment: @gbianchi claro, me faltó especificar en lo que pregunté si tampoco tiene usuario root, o con privilegios similares, por eso lo de "mismo caso".

Comment: si tengo un usuario root, lo que me refiero que si tengo el usuario pepe pero no tiene permisos para crear usuarios como le doy permisos para que crea usuario.

Comment: La dupla usuario-host es importante; agrega a tu pregunta el resultado de `SELECT user, host FROM mysql.user WHERE user='pepe'`. Si te devuelve mas de un registro indica a cual deseas otorgar el permiso. Por otro lado, ¿podemos asumir que el usuario pepe no necesitará el permiso para otorgar ese mismo permiso a otro usuario?.

Comment: Lo estoy haciendo a través de MySQL Workbench